# Не могу установить вычисляемые свойства класса

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста понять, почему я получаю ошибку и не могу установить вычисляемое свойство. Вот детали проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис для вычисляемого свойства следующий:

```
var elementsCount: Int { return self.restaurantNames.count }
```

Еслы же ты собираешься создать lazy свойство, то тогда нужно писать так:

```
lazy var elementsCount: Int = { 
    return self.restaurantNames.count 
}()
```

Или же в простом примере, как у тебя, этого будет достаточно

```
lazy var elementsCount: Int = self.restaurantNames.count
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое!